# Error 403 when trying to play the direct URL of the generated blogger video with curl

Tags: php, curl, blogger, http-status-code-403, google-blogger-api

when trying to reproduce the url rescued from the code below I get a 403 error, but when opening the url directly it works `https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz8fGJIfh9owHm8_SRdSkqD8g5Y9pnwKdDak1KzDrzPQG1aJigXD2AK-G_QD2-NQomPJXMV4aG_eG7ft_abAK07fZbY_I25kkdfgOguD0lrU0y-qR1JdbQX7AYsm3XK7rOUBKCD`

`https://rr1---sn-p5qlsndr.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1649837590&ei=lRVWYvasO-aF_9EPw9Ct-As&ip=18.207.249.251&id=0278c50fe6a211d5&itag=22&source=blogger&mh=8g&mm=31&mn=sn-p5qlsndr&ms=au&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=16&susc=bl&eaua=do0w1CEA3T4&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&dur=240.396&lmt=1649790419999233&mt=1649808299&txp=1311224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,susc,eaua,mime,vprv,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIhALPcfgLupszvnU93pLJFJguqbl2i6bs-XOWTCHuU48-OAiBiHJkRFt0L3hGfz_rix-T4q1ZMFg_LuaKmQptafhNGdg%3D%3D&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRAIgVLt5vtKphkKg-tnC9qC4wIG8sQdfyA_rxdKuAqkSJUkCIHdz8F2p9c8Uk5GagGSKCqG5ksVc3zlo7efGBF1cKY30&title=Kaginado%202%20Epis%C3%B3dio%201`

```html
$url = "https://www.blogger.com/video.g?token=AD6v5dz8fGJIfh9owHm8_SRdSkqD8g5Y9pnwKdDak1KzDrzPQG1aJigXD2AK-G_QD2-NQomPJXMV4aG_eG7ft_abAK07fZbY_I25kkdfgOguD0lrU0y-qR1JdbQX7AYsm3XK7rOUBKCD";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open it from the browser, you will send more data such as **cookie** or **referrer**. Probably they will check this information.
One option is to copy requests as curl in chrome(or probably in many browsers). in chrome, you can open developer tools(`View -> Developer -> Developer Tools`) and then you can click on Network Tab. then you can see network requests. you can right-click on one of them and then go to `copy -> copy as curl`, this command has all data